# Hide a part of value without changing it in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select a value from a table but want to display a portion of it to user. Is there any way to mask/hide a part of that value through a **direct query** ?Is there any function/method to display/mask a part of selected value

- Example:

  Column1
    JimLee

I need value as 'JimLee', which will directly come using -select colomn1 from X, but how display it as **'Jim'** only to users.
I have phrased this question according to my tools limitation

Comment: Always first 3 characters, or until second upper case letter?

Comment: first 3 chars in this case but main issue is how to hide a portion of any value

Comment: select substr(columnname, 1, 3) from tablename

Comment: but then it will store value 'Jim' only instead of 'JimLee' at backend I guess because u have substringed it to only 3 chars

Comment: Are you copying data from one table to another, and want to show the first 3 chars? Fix it in the display routine.

Comment: You need value as `JimLee`, then the **direct query** must return `JimLee`. How could you want the **direct query** both return `JimLee` and `Jim`? Magic?

Comment: What would your logic be? It might be give me all characters before second upper case character or all characters before first space character etc...

Comment: @jarlh - I'm using data from same table 
as display only one portion of string

Comment: @P.Salmon - Just hide any portion or even a letter just to display without changing real value

Comment: @Pham X. Bach - I thought there could be any way to get full name and display a portion only to user

Comment: @Imtiaz you cannot get full name and hide part of full name at the same time with only one **direct query**. Or you fail to express your intention IMO.

Comment: @Pham X. Bach- I meant this only, anyways if we could

Comment: Database could only return result, it cannot distinguish from you and your user to return `JimLee` and `Jim`, respectly. You should do it manually in your front-end.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a repalce  in select

```
select replace( Column1, right(Column1, length(Column1)-3 ), '***')
from mytable;
```

or for not show after the 3rd char

```
select replace( Column1, right(Column1, length(Column1)-3 ), '')
from mytable;
```

in this case you can use a simply left

```
select left(Column1, 3)
from mytable;
```

Comment: By doing that it will show  '*'  but I need not to show any thing at that place

Comment: asnwer  updated  for sho anythings  ..  hope is useful

Comment: no brother when we use function select replace() it takes replaced value as true value -for  'JimLee' it will take replaced 3 chars 'Jim' only as real value

I needed it to display 'Jim' only but value as  'JimLee' behind 3 chars

Comment: your comment are not clear .. anyway the answer  provided  should cover both case with whitout substitution of char .

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for substr().

```
select substr(column1, 1, 3)
  from X
;
```

[mysql-substr-function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substr-function.php)

Comment: this will not take full name-'JimLee' but only 3 chars as value 'Jim' b/c u have substringed that

Answer (score 0):

at first i thought you want to get Jim as a result, then this will do the job

```
select substr(column1, 1, 3) from tablename
```

then you said something about keeping the fullname for the backend but want to display different things, so i guess you need both value in your query like this

```
select column1 as fullName,substr(column1, 1, 3) as displayName from tablename
```

you can use the displayName in your front end, while using the fullName when you throw it to the backend